# Getting Unique Foreign Keys in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Suppose my model looks like this:

```
class Farm(models.Model):
   name = ...

class Tree(models.Model):
   farm = models.ForeignKey(Farm)
```

...and I get a `QuerySet` of `Tree` objects. How do I determine what farms are represented in that `QuerySet`?

Comment: By "unique" do you mean "distinct"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in

```
Farm.objects.filter(tree__in=TreeQuerySet)
```

Comment: nice, I think that is a well-performing way to go.  Especially for a very large Tree qs?  -- compared to my 'bring it into memory' way.

Answer (score 4):

There might be a better way to do it with the Django ORM and keep it lazy but you can get what you want with regular python (off the top of my head):

```
>>> set([ t.farm for t in qs ])
```

Comment: That was what I was about to put in.

Comment: That'll work since I have to iterate over them anyway later on. Thanks.

Comment: The square brackets aren't necessary here, you can use: `set(t.farm for t in qs)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to have the database do the work for you:

```
farms = qs.values_list('farm', flat=True).distinct() 
#values_list() is new in Django 1.0
```

return value should evaluate to something like:

```
(<Farm instance 1>, <Farm instance5>)
```

were farms will be those that have trees in that particular query set.

For all farms that have trees, use `qs = Tree.objects`

Keep in mind that if you add `order_by('some_other_column')` then distinct will apply to the distinct combinations of 'farm' and 'some_other_column', because other column will also be in the sql query for ordering. I think it's a limitation (not an intended feature) in the api, it's described in the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct).

Comment: so this could be qs.values('farm').distinct()?  Does this return a flat list or a qs or what? .. should look in the docs...

Comment: That will give you ALL the farms. The question ask for the farms related the the tree qs only.

Comment: Just replace `Tree.objects` with the appropriate Tree queryset and it will not give you all the farms.

Comment: so then qs.values_list('farm', flat=True).distinct() would work too to create a flat list or I have broken it?